# OOP Class Design

Tags: c#, oop

I have this code,

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public object CommonMethod<T>()
    {
        //Common code

        CustomMethod(); //Call child method

        return (T)CustomObject;
    }

    internal abstract void CustomMethod();
}


public class ChildClass : BaseClass
{
    public MyDTO CommonMethod()
    {
        return (MyDTO)base.CommonMethod<MyDTO>(); //Call Base class common code
    }

    internal override void CustomMethod()
    {
        //Custom Code, specific to child class
    }
}
```

I have some common code which I have placed in the base class (BaseClass.CommonMethod),
But finally same method should run child class specific code (ChildClass.CustomMethod).

Is this implementation correct or is there any other preferred/better implementation to achieve this?

### EDIT

Final code (Updated according to the answers) :

```
public abstract class BaseClass<T> where T : IDTO
{
    public T CommonMethod()
    {
        //Common code

        CustomMethod(); //Call child method

        return (T)CustomObject;
    }

    internal abstract void CustomMethod();
}


public class ChildClass : BaseClass<MyDTO>
{
    internal override void CustomMethod()
    {
        //Custom Code, specific to child class
    }
}
```

Comment: if it's common why have it on the child as well?

Comment: @AD.Net Actually, only the common part of code is moved to BaseClass but the rest is still in shild class..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With small corrections your code looks good. You don't need to override CommonMethod, though, if you put return value as T:

```
public abstract class BaseClass<T>
{
    public T CommonMethod()
    {
        //Common code

        T result = CustomMethod(); //Call child method

        return result;
    }

    internal abstract T CustomMethod();
}

public class ChildClass : BaseClass<MyDTO>
{
    internal override MyDTO CustomMethod()
    {
        //Custom Code, specific to child class
    }
}
```

In my example I assumed that you return CustomObject from CustomMethod, otherwise I'm not quite sure where are you getting this object from.

Comment: Sorry, my actual `CommonMethod` has parameters to pass in from the child class so I guess there's no way to remove the overriding...

Comment: Removed the `CommonMethod` and used abstract properties to access parameter data, from BaseClass CommonMethod. Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need the cast `(MyDTO)base.CommonMethod<MyDTO>();` as your base method is already casting the result.

You will need to make sure that `CustomObject` can be cast to `T`, that bit looks fishy to me.

`CustomerObject` must inherit from `MyDTO`, therefore `T` must implement `MyDTO` (*I think*)

Comment: Regarding the "make sure that CustomObject can be cast to T", something like `public object CommonMethod<T>() where T : IDTO` will fix this, right??